Check If Equal Value in Multiple Arrays
I have 3 arrays named "localCodes", "standardCodes", and "specialCodes". I am trying to confirm if there are any distinct values that appear in all 3 arrays.
What is the most efficient way of going about this?
EDIT:
Below is the code I was playing with, I just feel like there is a simpler way here that I am not getting
Example data set:
localCodes = [1,2,3,4]
standardCodes = [10,2,11,44]
specialCodes = [99,98,89,2]

With that set I would want to return true because 2 is found in each of the 3 arrays.
var longest = localCodes
var longFlag = 'local'
if(standardCodes.length > longest.length){
    longest = standardCodes
    longFlag = 'standard'
}
if(specialCodes.length > longest.length){
    longest = specialCodes
    longFlag = 'special'
}

for(l=0; l<longest.length; l++){
    if(longFlag == 'local'){
        //code here
    }
    if(longFlag == 'standard'){
        //code here
    }
    if(longFlag == 'special'){
        //code here
    }
}


do you have an example? what have you tried?

@qqq I just edited my code into the question

do you have the values as well and wanted result?

Are you trying to check if a specific value exits in all three? Or are you trying to find where all three overlap?

@VLAZ if ANY value exists in all 3. Once I know that there is at least 1 value that is in all 3 i'd be all set

@qqq Edited again

if you have [1, 1, 2], [1, 3] and [1, 4] would 1 be a valid result? It exists in all three, but shows up twice in the first array.

If by simpler way you mean something short. You can do something like this: localCodes.some((o) => standardCodes.includes(o) && specialCodes.includes(o)).  It is not that efficient and .includes(..) works only with primitives and references

You can map all the lists to a collection of sets and then reduce them by calling intersection.


const
  localCodes    = [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
  standardCodes = [10,  2, 11, 44],
  specialCodes  = [99, 98, 89,  2];
  
const getIntersectingValues = (...arr) => [...arr
  .map(arr => new Set(arr))
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc.intersection(cur))];
  
const sharedValues = getIntersectingValues(
  localCodes,
  standardCodes,
  specialCodes
);

console.log(sharedValues); // [2]



If you just want a boolean, you can check the resulting size of the reduced intersection:


const
  localCodes    = [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
  standardCodes = [10,  2, 11, 44],
  specialCodes  = [99, 98, 89,  2];
  
const hasIntersectingValues = (...arr) => arr
  .map(arr => new Set(arr))
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc.intersection(cur))
  .size > 0;
  
const hasIntersection = hasIntersectingValues(
  localCodes,
  standardCodes,
  specialCodes
);

console.log(hasIntersection); // true



